# How to render a tree in Twig

Tags: loops, recursion, tree, twig

I would like to render a tree with an undetermined depth (children of children of children, etc.). I need to loop through the array recursively; how can I do this in Twig?

Answer (score 126):

I played around with [domi27's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326482/how-to-render-a-tree-in-twig/8341154#8341154) and came up with this. I made a nested array as my tree, ['link']['sublinks'] is null or another array of more of the same.

**Templates**

The sub-template file to recurse with:

```
<!--includes/menu-links.html-->
{% for link in links %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ link.href }}">{{ link.name }}</a>
        {% if link.sublinks %}
            <ul>
                {% include "includes/menu-links.html" with {'links': link.sublinks} %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in the main template, call this (kind of redundant 'with' stuff there):

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    {% include "includes/menu-links.html" with {'links':links} only %}
</ul>
```

**Macros**

A similar effect can be achieved with macros:

```
<!--macros/menu-macros.html-->
{% macro menu_links(links) %}
    {% for link in links %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ link.href }}">{{ link.name }}</a>
            {% if link.sublinks %}
                <ul>
                    {{ _self.menu_links(link.sublinks) }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

In the main template, do this:

```
{% import "macros/menu-macros.html" as macros %}
<ul class="main-menu">
    {{ macros.menu_links(links) }}
</ul>
```

Comment: Very good, thank you! If you want to use the macro in the same template you can use `{{ _self.menu_links(links) }}`.

Comment: thank you, the thought of this made my brain hurt but your answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: I had one issue with my project with comments. subcomments(sublinks) were also included in main collection(links). so before include I had to check if comment had a 'parent' entry.

Comment: Using `{{_self.menu_links}}` is a **bad practice**! Read a note here: [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html)

When you define a macro in the template where you are going to use it, you might be tempted to call the macro directly via _self.input() instead of importing it; even if seems to work, this is just a side-effect of the current implementation and it won't work anymore in Twig 2.x.

You should import macroses locally once again insite `menu_links`

Answer (score 42):

### Twig 2.0 - 2.11

If you want to use a **macro in the same template**, you should use something like this to stay **compatible with Twig 2.x**:

```
{% macro menu_links(links) %}
    {% import _self as macros %}
    {% for link in links %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ link.href }}">{{ link.name }}</a>
            {% if link.sublinks %}
                <ul>
                    {{ macros.menu_links(link.sublinks) }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as macros %}

<ul class="main-menu">
    {{ macros.menu_links(links) }}
</ul>
```

This extends `random-coder`'s answer and incorporates `dr.scre`'s hint to the [Twig documentation about macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) to now use `_self`, but import locally.

### Twig >= 2.11

As of **Twig 2.11**, you can omit the `{% import _self as macros %}`, as inlined macros are imported automatically under the `_self` namespace (see [Twig announcement: Automatic macro import](https://symfony.com/blog/simpler-macros-in-twig-templates#automatic-macro-import)):

```
{# {% import _self as macros %} - Can be removed #}

<ul class="main-menu">
    {{ _self.menu_links(links) }} {# Use _self for inlined macros #}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running PHP 5.4 or higher, there is a wonderful new solution (as of May 2016) to this problem by Alain Tiemblo: https://github.com/ninsuo/jordan-tree.

It's a "tree" tag that serves this exact purpose. Markup would look like this:

```
{% tree link in links %}
    {% if treeloop.first %}<ul>{% endif %}

    <li>
        <a href="{{ link.href }}">{{ link.name }}</a>
        {% subtree link.sublinks %}
    </li>

    {% if treeloop.last %}</ul>{% endif %}
{% endtree %}
```

Comment: You can't pass additional variables to `subtree`. In my case, the code needs to know whether there will be more children and it passes the number of levels to the macro so it can do a `<div class="{{ classes[current_level].wrapper }} {% if levels > current_level %}accordion-wrapper{% endif %}">`. Calculating this would require iterating the current level a second time just to capture whether there are any children.

Answer (score 1):

First I thought this may be solved in a straightforward way, but it isn't that easy.

You need to create logic, maybe with a PHP class method, when to include a Twig subtemplate and when not.

```
<!-- tpl.html.twig -->
<ul>
    {% for key, item in menu %}
        {# Pseudo Twig code #}
        {% if item|hassubitem %}
            {% include "subitem.html.tpl" %}
        {% else %}
            <li>{{ item }}</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So you could use the special [Twig loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable), which is available inside a Twig *for loop*. But I'm not sure about the scope of this *loop* variable.

This and other information are available on [Twigs "for" Docu](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html)!

Answer (score 1):

Took [flu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326482/how-to-render-a-tree-in-twig/23135522#23135522) and modified it a little:

```
{# Macro #}

{% macro tree(items) %}
    {% import _self as m %}
        {% if items %}
        <ul>
            {% for i in items %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ i.url }}">{{ i.title }}</a>
                    {{ m.tree(i.items) }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{# Usage #}

{% import 'macros.twig' as m %}

{{ m.tree(items) }}
```

Answer (score -1):

The answers here lead my to my solution.

I have a category entity with a self-referencing many-to-one association (parent to children).

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
 */
private $parent;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $children;
```

In my Twig template I am rendering the tree view like this:

```
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
    {% if category.parent == null %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
            {% if category.children|length > 0 %}
            <ul>
            {% for category in category.children %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: What if you have more than one level of category hierarchy?