# Twig loop for nested comment in a Symfony-Doctrine blog

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony

I am trying to implement a comment section on a blog with Symfony and Doctrine, using Twig templates.

I am having some trouble trying to implement a response system for my comments. I would like to have something like this:

```
<div class="comment">
    <p>This is comment number 1</p>
    <div class="response">
        <p>This is a response to comment number 1</p>
        <div class="response">
            <p>This is a response to response just above</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I would like to have sort of a nested comment system.

I have a Comment entity with a `$response` property having a OneToOne Relation with another Comment entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Comment")
 */
protected $response;
```

In my controller, I just get my comments like this:

```
$comments = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager()
                    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Comment')
                    ->findByArticle($article);
```

Now I am trying to create the HTML (Twig) but I don't know how to loop throught all comment and associated response so I can create the HTML as I wrote just above...

Anyone who can help me with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is recurrence. You have a few options to choose from, one of them is using a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html).

Create twig file with your macro:

```
{# src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Default/_macro.html.twig #}

{% macro print_comments_recursively(comment) %}
    <div class="response">
        <p>{{ comment }}</p> {# implement __toString on your Comment class or print appropriate property #}
        {% if comment.response is not null  %}
            {{ _self.print_comments_recursively(comment.response) }}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Import macro in your view and use it:

```
{% import 'AppBundle:Default:_macro.html.twig' as macros %}
<div class="comment">
    <p>{{ comment }}</p>
    {% if comment.response %}
        {{ macros.print_comments_recursively(comment.response) }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Here you have similar problem, already solved, with other solutions: [How to render a tree in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326482/twig-how-to-render-a-tree)

Comment: Great solution ! Thank's