# show unlimited children category on twig

Tags: php, twig

I have array like this:

```
array(
  'id' => 1,
  'children' => array(
    'id' => 5,
    'children' =>
    array(
      'id' => 6,
      'children' => 'none',
    ),
    array(
      'id' => 8,
      'children' => array(...),
    )
  )
)
```

with php code can call Recursive Function to echo it. but in twig i can't call Recursive Function.

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <div class="category">
      <div class="id">{{ category.id }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

my code just print first level of array and not other!

Comment: is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326482/how-to-render-a-tree-in-twig

Comment: you could include the same view again so that the behavior is the same as in your recursive function. Like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467939/2401386)

Answer (score 0):

You can with blocks:

```
{% set foo = { 'hello': { 'hello': { 'hello': 'swagg' }, 'foo': 'bar' } } %}


{% block test %}
<ul>
    {% for keyOfFoo, f in foo %}
    <li>
        {{ keyOfFoo }}
        {% if f is iterable %}
            {% with { foo: f } %}
            {{ block('test') }}
            {% endwith %}
        {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock test %}
```

Here is live demo: https://twigfiddle.com/r35pae

But there is also many other options. Like [include](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/include.html) loop. Or [embedded](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html).