# recursive html call doesn't return the correct value

Tags: recursion, twig

here I am trying to recursive call an html template where it loops through the category with some certain custom fields that are attached to certain categories everything works fine but the counter (`maxCategories`) which is going to be responsible for showing only a certain number of categories or sub-categories.

**CODE:**

```
{% block homepage_category_lister %}
{% macro category_links(navigationTree, maxCategories = 0) %}

    {% for treeItem in navigationTree %}

        {% if maxCategories < 6 %}
        {% set category = treeItem.category %}
            {% set name = treeItem.category.translated.name %}

            {% if treeItem.category.customFields['custom__test'] == 'yes' %}



                {% block home_categories_listing_box %}
                        <div class="category--box">
                            <a href="{{category_url(category)}}"
                               itemprop="url"
                               title="{{ name | striptags }}">
                                {% sw_thumbnails 'home--categories--teaser--images' with {
                                    media: category.media,
                                    sizes: {
                                        'default': '4500px'
                                    },
                                    attributes: {
                                        'class': 'home--categories--teaser--images',
                                        'alt': (category.media.translated.alt ?: ''),
                                        'title': (category.media.translated.title ?: ''),
                                        'data-object-fit': 'cover',
                                        'loading': 'lazy'
                                    }
                                } %}
                                <span itemprop="name" class="category--box--name">
                            {{ name | striptags }}
                        </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                {% endblock %}
                {% set maxCategories = maxCategories + 1 %}

            {% endif %}


            {% block home_categories_listing_box_recrussive %}

                {% if treeItem.children != null %}
                    {{ _self.category_links(treeItem.children, maxCategories) }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endblock %}

        {% endif %}


    {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
{% endblock %}
```

**PROBLEM:**

- the number that the `maxCategories` returns look like this **1(category**), **2(category)**,**2(sub-category)**, **3(sub-category)**, **4 (last sub-category element)** , **2(category)** and **3(category)** which means the `maxCategories` is not being passed correctly but still I cant find the error in my code but it looks logical am I messing something?

**Solutions I treid:**

- removed the sub-categories and only used the parent categories it gave me the same counter result which is: 1,2,2...etc.
- tried breaking my code to multiple `for` + `if` statements  + templates instead of one recursive template (works fine but I would like to get a solution to my problem with the recursive)

**pictures:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you are trying to do is unclear, because you haven't given a *expected result*.  That said ..  You are setting `{% set maxCategories = maxCategories + 1 %}` at the bottom of the loop in no **conditional** so it's always adding +1 and at the top of the loop you are saying `if maxCategories  < 6` which **includes** 0 -- If you have 100 categories will always end up stopping (or skipping in this case) at 7

Comment: hey @Zak my expected result should look like this 1(category) 2(sub-category), 3(sub-category) 4(sub-category) 5(category) 6(category) but my code does 1(category) 2(sub-category), 2(sub-category) 3(sub-category) 4(sub-category) 5(sub-category) 2(category) 3(category) etc. instead. and in my case it doesn't skip or stop at 7

Comment: You can't do recursion with default templates. Have a look at macro's

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render a tree in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326482/how-to-render-a-tree-in-twig)

Comment: Hey @DarkBee the recursion works fine the only problem that I am facing that the counter for the limit of category isn't counting as it normally should.

Comment: That's because included templates have their own scope and can't alter/update variables from their caller...

Comment: thanks for replying @DarkBee, do you have any suggestion of how I can go around it or is it not possible ? because from what I am facing I see that the value of the `maxCategories` variable/counter is acting differently after using macros, the counter is starting/continuing to count depending on the depth of the category and category for example: **1(apple), oranges category-children: (1(Blood oranges)2(Mandarin oranges)) berries category-children: (1(Blueberry) 2(Raspberry) 3(Strawberry)), (Strawberry category-child: ( 1(Strasberry)), 2(bananas) 3(pineapple)**

Comment: Look at the linked question/answers. You'll need to resort to macros

Comment: @DarkBee (thanks for the macros suggestion I am using it right now) after a lot of testing and trying I am still stuck on the same problem....which is I think a recursive loop problem where the `maxCategories` new value isn't being passed up from the second loop to the previous ones correctly .... but I cant find the problem..it looks normal to me

Comment: at the end of my for loop I am getting two values from the variable `maxCategories`  when switching from sub-category to category or other way around... which for me dosent make any sense how could a variable have two values

Comment: What is `maxCategories`? The max nesting level or the amount of shown categories?

Comment: I've made you a small demo (based on if `maxCategories` is actually the max nesting level) - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/mhmtjx)

Comment: Hey, @DarkBee `maxCategories` isn't the max nesting level in my case it's maximum categories to show

Comment: Updated [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/mhmtjx/2) with `maxCategories` as the actual max. categories to be shown

Comment: @DarkBee thanks for the reply, I already tried this solution and it unfortunately didn't work ... it still resets/continues the count depending on the depth of the category for example: **category is 1 sub-category is 2 child of the second sub-category is 3 sub-category is 3 category is 2**

Comment: Go through the second demo again then and try to spot the difference. The big difference here is the following line: `{% set currentCategories = currentCategories + (treeItem.children|length) %}` which accounts for the correct number of categories. As seen in the output, the categories are limited by the setting `maxCategories`

Comment: @DarkBee I did a `dump()`  at the end of the `{% if treeItem.children|default and maxCategories > currentCategories %}` statement  and it showed me the value I am looking for which.... is for example: **category is 1 sub-category is 2 child of the second sub-category is 3 sub-category is 4 category is 5 ....** but as soon the loop goes to the top to continue looping through the rest it resets and shows my example from my previous comment. (I also noticed after dumping the value at the end of the for loop that I am getting two values from the variable `currentCategories`  for example: 5 and 6)

Comment: I did test if `currentCategories` change its type which for me impossible thing but I did it just to make sure and it doesn't....I think the problem is that the outer loop is somehow isn't registering the values that are done in the inner loop by this I mean when there is a switch from children to parent the values and changes that are done in the child loop isn't being passed to the parent loop but the other way around works fine